# Load a very large Image in android

Tags: android, ios, image, large-data

Assumes I have a picture, it very large images or other sets of content where you are only looking at small bits at a time, because you can start seeing your content without having to load it all into memory at once.

In iOs we can use CATiledLayer to repeatedly draw tiles to fill up view’s background

In Android I can see Google Map, It also load each part of map when you scroll but I don't understand what is solution of them.

I want know what is the solution same CATiledLayer in Android or other to load very large Image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can actually scale down the bitmap according to the size of the image view.

Don't give wrap_content in width and height try to give a relative width and height. 
use

```
ImageView.getheight()
ImageView.getWidth()
```

get the size and load according to it
see this link
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#read-bitmap

Comment: That mean I still keep original in memory and rescale down when I load other part of picture or zoom it ?

Comment: no you will load  the image according to the size specified by you. the original image will be in the permanent storage.

Comment: what happen if i zoom or scroll the image and need resolution best ?

Comment: Thanks, I think that could be a solution, I will check it and feedback after have the result

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library load images efficiently and manage caching them instead of downloading them again. I suggest [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). This [tutorial](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en) compares between them and explains few features.
I hope it's useful.